# TimeSpan not getting the correct remaining time

Tags: c#, timespan

I have this line:

```
TimeSpan duration = 
       Convert.ToDateTime(localSettings.Containers["userInfo"].Values["nextSpinUnlockTime"]) 
     - Convert.ToDateTime(localSettings.Containers["userInfo"].Values["spinTimeStarted"]);
```

If the `nextSpinUnlockTime` within the local container stores 11/08/2015 10:54:23 and `spinTimeStarted` stores 11/08/2015 07:54:23 why does `duration` store -800 in milliseconds?

Does anyone understand what is wrong..

I only debug that line, and on that line `duration`'s milliseconds equals -800

**UPDATE**

I have this (something i forgot to mention and add):

```
localSettings.Containers["userInfo"].Values["nextSpinUnlockTime"] = Convert.ToDateTime(localSettings.Containers["userInfo"].Values["spinTimeStarted"]).AddHours(3).ToString();
```

I've debugged and the reason for the minus milliseconds was because it wasn't adding 3 hours as expected. Does anyone understand why?

Comment: Why do you have two different format dates?

Comment: Have you ever _really_ check the `DateTime` values that returned? For example; assign them in a different variables and see their exact values.

Comment: @RonBeyer It is just to work out differences at different states

Comment: @KTOV I'm asking why they are in different **formats**, the first one has : separators, the second one has -'s.

Comment: @SonerGönül Yes I have. Assigned them to a `Text` property of a `TextBlock` read the `Text` property at debug.. and the values where as mentioned above

Comment: There's not enough here to reproduce the problem but my guess is one of those utc and the other is local.

Comment: I agree with @SonerGönül.  Separate the parsing and the subtracting so you can easily debug and see exactly what `DateTime` values your input is being parsed into.

Comment: @RonBeyer Oops. I did that accidentally.

Comment: The second string is not a valid DateTime

Comment: @recursive Hence why I said `TextBlock` and don't be to quick to assume. `DateTime.ToString();` :)

Comment: I get a `TimeSpan` of 3 hours when putting in those exact strings.  You need to debug and see exactly what string values and then what `DateTime` values those strings are parsed into.

Comment: @juharr Okay, I'll debug everything individually now

Comment: Are you only looking at the `Milliseconds` property of Timespan, and not the `Hours` or `Minutes`? What does the `TotalMilliseconds` value read? I'm guessing that even though you are using the `DateTime.ToString()` you are missing the millisecond component of the dates, and if you look at the `.Milliseconds` property, it only gives you the fractional part of a second, `TotalMilliseconds` is the entire timespan represented as milliseconds.

Comment: @juharr Updated question

Comment: @RonBeyer Updated the question :)

Comment: Is it possible that something else updates nextSpinUnlockTime?  Also is there a reason to store them as strings instead of `DateTime`s?

Comment: @juharr Nope nothing else updates them.. And nope, regardless what I store it as, it stores as a string

Comment: @KTOV I meant what is `localSettings`?  The `Values` is either storing `string` and your stuck, or it's storing `object` and you could put the `DateTime`s in and then cast when you pull them out instead of doing `ToString`.

Comment: @juharr Surely `ToString` isn't the reason why `AddHours` isn't working?

Comment: @KTOV I'm not saying it's the problem, just that if you can avoid all the parsing and formatting it would be better.

Comment: Okay, yup i understand.. Currently im just focusing on this problem because its getting a bit out of hand now

Comment: Try to write a short complete console application that demonstrates your problem.  As it is I cannot reproduce any of your issues as I don't have whatever `localSettings` is.

Comment: @juharr I've added an answer myself, thanks for your help!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a very long time of smacking my head against the desk, I tried:

```
DateTime newDate = currentDateAndTime.AddHours(3);
```

It came out with the correct result as it added the additonal 3 hours, I knew `DateTime` objects are immutable, but I didn't understand why it didn't work because I wasn't assigning the value back to `currentDateAndTime` for example:

```
currentDateAndTime = currentDateAndTime.AddHours(3);
```

Instead I was doing:

```
localSettings.Containers["userInfo"].Values["nextSpinUnlockTime"] = Convert.ToDateTime(localSettings.Containers["userInfo"].Values["spinTimeStarted"]).AddHours(3).ToString();
```

However, it's working and I couldn't be any happier!

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Default `ToString()` method for `DateTime` puts the value up to *seconds*:

```
  DateTime sample = new DateTime(2015, 11, 6, 15, 14, 13, 123);

  // 06.11.2015 15:14:13
  // Note 123 (milliseconds) absence
  Console.Write(sample.ToString());

  // To check value up to millisecond use ".fff" Format
  // 06.11.2015 03:14:13.123 
  Console.Write(sample.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff"));
```

So in your case, both values have *milliseconds*, but they are not printed out:

```
  DateTime first = new DateTime(2015, 11, 8, 10, 54, 23, 900);
  DateTime second = new DateTime(2015, 11, 8, 10, 54, 23, 100);

  TimeSpan duration = second - first; 

  // The output: 
  //  08.11.2015 10:54:23 <- default ToString() - up to seconds
  //  08.11.2015 10:54:23 <- default ToString() - up to seconds
  // -00:00:00.8000000
  Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, first, second, duration));
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Unfortunately not the answer though

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be in the Convert.ToDateTime call. I can't see any millisecond in your examples. Why don't you try providing some details about your culture to the convert method?

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
var start = Convert.ToDateTime("11/08/2015 10:54:23", culture);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using `DateTime.Subtract()`:

```
TimeSpan duration = Convert.ToDateTime(localSettings.Containers["userInfo"].Values["nextSpinUnlockTime"]).Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime(localSettings.Containers["userInfo"].Values["spinTimeStarted"]));
```

And you may want to check the `duration.TotalMilliseconds`

Comment: `DateTime.Subtract` and `operator - (DateTime, DateTime)` will give the same results.

Comment: Yes, but to rule out  (which honestly shouldn't be the case) an overloaded operator, might as well use the intended `.Subtract(DateTime)` function. I do still stand by the `.TotalMilliseconds` portion though. He has mentioned `.Milliseconds` storing `-800` when he is looking for 3 hours, but I have not seen any mention of him looking into the `.Hours` or `.TotalHours` properties.

Comment: Based on the date times -800 is wrong for both `TotalMilliseconds` and `Milliseconds`, so while it's important to know the difference I seriously doubt it has anything to do with the root problem.

Comment: If the values he is subtracting are actually a difference of 3 hours and 800 milliseconds, a TimeSpan object `duration` in his example will have the following: `duration.Millisecond = -800` and `duration.Hours = -3`, while `duration.TotalMilliseconds = -10800800` and `duration.TotalHours = -3`.